# Why is my salesforce org asking for security code every day?

Tags: security

When I am trying to log in with `sandbox (or production)` credentials, every day asking for a security code which I receive on my phone.

This is happening even though I logged in to the same system every day.

Can any one please help me find out how to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Dynamic IP address/Different browser? Have a look at your login history and see if your IP is different each day.

Comment: Could also be if you're using inPrivate/incognito/private window etc...

Comment: yeah may be issue with Dynamic  IP address. One solution goto your user's profile --> below ip range section just `0.0.0.0` and `255.255.255.255`... solve your problem

Comment: @user28888 issue resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Issue with Dynamic IP address.

One solution goto your `user's profile --> below ip range section`

just Add `0.0.0.0 and 255.255.255.255`

Now with this user's credential. You can login from any ip address system..

Cheers :-)

Comment: @Minion You should wary of arbitrarily setting a global IP range for a user profile, especially if that profile has admin permissions to a production system. By doing so you are removing or reducing some of the security features baked into the platform for that set of users. For developer orgs, probably not an issue though...I do it all the time.